# Return function status for loop

Tags: function, go

I've the following function which iterate on list of response and if success print ok or error, at the end (after the function finished to execute) I need to return http 200 (if `ok` or `200` conditon is valid always) or http 500 if failure (even one failure) .I can use some flag (which I want to avoid) but is there a cleaner way to do it in Golang?

```
func getResults(results chan resultsList) {
    for res := range results {
        if res.Data != "ok" && res.Data != 200 {
            fmt.Println("error")
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("finish time %s \n", res.Name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the function should return failure even for a single failure, why do you want to keep processing the channel after the first failure ? To drain it or for other reasons ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the "return early" style in these cases. Here is some example:

```
import (
   "fmt"
   "log"
)

func getResults(results chan resultsList) error {
   for res := range results {
      if res.Data != "ok" || res.Data != 200 {
         return fmt.Errorf("Data: %v", res.Data)
      }
      fmt.Println("finish time", res.Name)
   }
   return nil
}

func main() {
   e := getResults(something)
   if e != nil {
      log.Fatal(e)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the way you wrote it is pretty clean already, to improve it you could use tagless switch statements, which would allow for overlapping conditions, meaning you could return detailed error messages for every error that may occour.

Other than that, you could maybe put a break statement into your if block, depending on wheather you want to know all errors or just if any error has occured.

Comment: ok, but how would you suggest to return the end result? if one iteration fails return 500 and if all success return 200...

Comment: Depends if you want to actually return those values/results. If you just want to print that there was an error, then you don't need to return anything, just print it. If you want to take action depending on which error happened then you could return a slice of unsigned integers, and iterate over that, or write the logic directly into the function you provided.